# Set fillable aliases in Laravel Model, based on env variable?

Tags: php, laravel

In my current Laravel 6 project, I have two different types of databases that have column names that can't be changed. The easiest solution I have determined is to create a function inside of my model to switch the `$fillable` value based on the return of a function. However, when trying to set the value of `protected $fillable = $this->aliasSwitch($is_local);` I get an error saying `Constant expression contains invalid operations` in my code editor. Is there something I am misunderstanding about protected variable types? And is there a work around I am not seeing?

Model:

```
public function __construct($env = '') {
        $prefix = $env ? $env.'_' : '';
        $this->is_local = config("shopify." . $prefix . "is_local");
    }

    protected $table = 'Product';

    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at','id','Error_msg'];

    protected $fillable = $this->aliasSwitch($is_local);

    protected function aliasSwitch($is_local) {
        if($is_local = true) {
            $fillable = ['Action','Destination'...];
        }
        elseif($is_local = false) {
            $fillable = ['AS4324' => 'Action', 'AS4255' => 'Destination'...];
        }
        return $fillable;
    }
```

I am expecting the `protected $fillable` to have the value returned by the `aliasSwitch()` return. I have tried setting `$fillable` as unprotected, but I am afraid of this for security reasons.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your database structure. You have two tables for the same model? But the column names in these tables are different? Why not have your aliases as part of localisation or presentation and thereby keep a single table?

Comment: @Spholt two different databases with completely different structures. Ones an old IBM and for local development we are using mysql. Hopefully that cleared things up

Comment: eek :(. Well, Wahyu's answer explains why you are getting the error. Just a piece of advice, if you are having to support that old IBM database, it may be worth also using one locally for development to avoid diverging too far from your production environment. You may end up with a fragile codebase where it works locally but not in production!

Comment: @Spholt that's exactly what I'm afraid of. I plan on learning a lot from this process. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.
>
> [Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

You need to define it through the constructor :

```php
protected $is_local = true; // default
protected $fillable;

public function __construct(array $attributes = []){
     parent::__construct($attributes);

     $this->fillable = $this->aliasSwitch($this->is_local);
}
```